# Is it possible to have conditional abbrev expansion?

Tags: abbrev

I have defined some abbreviations for org-mode, but I want them to conditionally expand. For example, `n2` expands to `N_{2}`, and I want to prevent that from happening in src-blocks.

The bottom of this page: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Expansion.html suggests I should use advice to achieve this. That doesn't seem too flexible though, I don't want all abbrevs to not work in src blocks, just some.

Are there other ways to get context-specific abbreviations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can tell the `abbrev` table to use an explicit function
to test whether or not to fire in a given instance.  The relevant
argument in `define-abbrev-table` is [`:enable-function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Table-Properties.html#Abbrev-Table-Properties), which,
according to the docstring, reads:

> `(define-abbrev-table TABLENAME DEFINITIONS &optional DOCSTRING &rest PROPS)`
>
> Define TABLENAME (a symbol) as an abbrev table name.
>   Define abbrevs in it according to DEFINITIONS, which is a list of elements
>   of the form (ABBREVNAME EXPANSION ...) that are passed to `define-abbrev`.
>   PROPS is a property list to apply to the table.
>   Properties with special meaning:
>
> (blah blah blah)
>
> - `:enable-function` can be set to a function of no argument which returns
>     non-nil if and only if the abbrevs in this table should be used for this
>     instance of `expand-abbrev`.

So: the following toy example (untested) should work:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'org-mode-abbrev-table
  '(("test1"  "this is a test")
    ("test2"  "this is also a test"))
  "Table of abbrevs that should NOT fire when in a source block."
  :enable-function (lambda ()
                     (not (org-in-src-block-p))))
```